# Rails, using build to create a nested object,  but it is not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My app has three models:

```
Thread (has_many :thread_apps)
ThreadApp (belongs_to :thread, has_many :forms, :as => :appable)
Form (belongs_to :app)

ThreadApp Fields: thread_id, form_id, appable_id, appable_type
```

What I want to be able to do is when creating a form, ensure that a ThreadApp record is also created to make the association:

Here is what I have:

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController

 def create
    @thread = Thread.find(params[:thread_id])
    @thread_app = @thread.thread_apps.new
    @form = @thread_app.forms.build(params[:form].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
    @form.save
    ....
```

This is saving the form nicely, but the thread_app associated is not being made? Any ideas why?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

callings `model.save` does not save associations unless you tell it to

you can set autosave

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :thread_app , :autosave => true
end
```

or call save on it in the controller

```
@thread_app.save
```

or you can take it out of the controller entirely
and do this with a callback

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :create_thread_app
   def create_thread_app
     self.thread_app ||= ThreadApp.create(...)
   end
end
```

or after_create, _before_validation_on_create, or any other call back would work

--**UPDATE**--

this might make a difference using create inse=tead of new, and `appables` that you specified as 'as'

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController

 def create
    @thread = Thread.find(params[:thread_id])
    @thread_app = @thread.thread_apps.create
    @form = @thread_app.appables.build(params[:form].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
    @form.save
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks. autosave doesn't appear to be having any effect

Comment: Can you advise on how I should be building the form object?

Comment: try putting autosave on the other object, look at the part on Unsaved objects http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
@thread_app = @thread.thread_apps.new
```

You should have:

```
@thread_app = @thread.thread_apps.create
```